# ActiveRecord reporting a failed validation, but there are no validations defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, rspec

I'm just starting to use RSpec with a new project (after being a minitest user for a while).  I've created a single MVC, called contracts.  Here is the model file:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :number, :plannedStart, :actualStart, :plannedCompletion, :actualCompletion
end
```

I've got a basic factory defined for Contracts (it was slightly more complex earlier, using sequence to generate novel names and numbers, but I removed all of that to try to simplify squashing this bug):

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :contract do

  end
end
```

Here are the specs (pretty much auto generated, except I added in the calls to the factory):

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'

describe ContractsController do
  render_views

  it "index action should render index template" do
    create(:contract)
    get :index
    response.should render_template(:index)
  end

  it "show action should render show template" do

    create(:contract)
    get :show, :id => Contract.first
    response.should render_template(:show)
  end

  it "new action should render new template" do
    get :new
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end

  it "create action should render new template when model is invalid" do

    Contract.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
    post :create
    response.should render_template(:new)
  end

  it "create action should redirect when model is valid" do

    Contract.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
    post :create
    response.should redirect_to(contract_url(assigns[:contract]))
  end

  it "edit action should render edit template" do
    create(:contract)
    get :edit, :id => Contract.first
    response.should render_template(:edit)
  end

  it "update action should render edit template when model is invalid" do
    create(:contract)
    Contract.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(false)
    put :update, :id => Contract.first
    response.should render_template(:edit)
  end

  it "update action should redirect when model is valid" do
    create(:contract)
    create(:contract)
    Contract.any_instance.stubs(:valid?).returns(true)
    put :update, :id => Contract.first
    response.should redirect_to(contract_url(assigns[:contract]))
  end

  it "destroy action should destroy model and redirect to index action" do
    create(:contract)
    contract = Contract.first
    delete :destroy, :id => contract
    response.should redirect_to(contracts_url)
    Contract.exists?(contract.id).should be_false
  end
end
```

When I run the spec, I get the following error message, but the number of these I get varies from run to run:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
./spec/controllers/contracts_controller_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
./spec/controllers/contracts_controller_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: 
./spec/controllers/contracts_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

10 examples, 3 failures, 7 passed

Finished in 0.360139 seconds
/Users/jlee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/controllers/contracts_controller_spec.rb ./spec/models/contract_spec.rb failed
```

I've implemented Databasecleaner just to make sure this wasn't some odd behavior problem relating to using transactions during testing, but to no avail.  Suggestions?  I have no validations defined, so its hard to understand how I could be failing validation.

Comment: The problem seems to do with the specs that cause a validation failure, but why that is triggering an error is a bit confusing.  I'll continue to research.

Answer (score 0):

The stub for :valid?  hangs around between tests, so I put the following in the before(:each) block:  Contract.any_instance.unstub(:valid?), and it cleared everything up.

Comment: If I was using fixtures, I imagine this wouldn't show up, as the stubbed tests show up at the end of the run.  It would be nice if things that have been stubbed only persist for the duration of a specific spec, but...